# install mod_php on RHEL 7 using official packages

Tags: php, rhel7

RHEL 7 includes `rh-php70-php` in the official repository. However, this module does not install mod_php.

I have tried all of the approaches for installing rh-php70-* and none of them installs and registers the appropriate php module. How does one do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `rh-php70-php` contains the following files:

```
[root@nas ~]# repoquery -l rh-php70-php
/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/rh-php70-php.conf
/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/15-rh-php70-php.conf
/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/librh-php70-php7.so
...
```

These files enable use of `mod_php` version 7 with Apache 2.4. However, you should **first enable the scl for the session**, then run apache. For example:

```
scl enable rh-php70 bash; systemctl restart httpd
```

For information on how to make the scl active at boot time, give a look [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/527703)

However, I strongly suggest you to use php7 via fpm, using the relevant `systemctl` service.